# Best place for CSS and LESS external libs in PhpStorm or PyCharm project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, phpstorm, pycharm

I want my IDE to see Bootstrap files for CSS classes autocompletion and on-the-fly LESS compiling. But I don't want to store Bootstrap inside my project folder structure and copy libraries in each project. How can I make IDE know where is libs?

Some approaches I tried.

1. Using relative paths. `@import '../../../../../Bootstrap 3/less/mixins';` does not look good. Moreover, despite import statement is correct (without red underlining), IDE does not "know" about imported mixins. When I just copy libraries, IDE "knows" about them.
2. Connect as JS libs. I see them in project files view. LESS syntax checker cannot locate them, no matter what path i specify. Import statement is underlined with red wavy line.

Now, I can use only copy and paste technique or use links (or directory junctions). I am not sure that this is correct way.

I tried this PhpStrom and PyCharm, but I suppose that WebStorm cannot resolve this problem too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a folder where your Bootstrap files are stored as additional content root to each of your projects (Settings/Directories, Add content root). See also [WEB-7452](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7452)

Comment: Thank for pointing out on that. I heard about that already and searched several times for _content root_ but today I looked for that without using search and found this. Thanks.

Comment: In PyCharm, I found _Project Structure_ instead of _Directories_.